# Uri with File:/// vs Content:// -- Retrieving music file info

Tags: android, uri, media, mediastore

I've noticed something odd about the behavior of my code and am hoping someone can shed some light.

```
        String temp = "file:///sdcard/music/05 Folsom Prison Blues.mp3";
        String temp2 = "content://media/external/audio/media/10";

        Uri uri = Uri.parse(temp);

        Cursor musiccursor = null;
        musiccursor = managedQuery(uri, null, null, null, null);

        try {
        if (musiccursor.moveToFirst()) {
            String title; 
            int titleColumn = musiccursor.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Audio.Media.TITLE); 
                title = musiccursor.getString(titleColumn);
            item.setText(title);
        }
```

The problem I'm noticing is that with temp2 everything runs fine, I'm able to get the song's title. But with temp musiccursor is null every time so we throw a nullpointerexception. Any idea what the difference is here? I've tried the encoded version of temp (converts spaces to %20 etc) and that doesn't work. I can use the uri that is created with temp2 to play the song using an intent no problem... Not sure what I'm missing here.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: yeah why are you using a content provider to retrieve a file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`file://` is not a scheme managed by a content provider (only `content://` is), and so a `ContentResolver` will not be able to do anything with it.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I appreciate it. The reason I'm ending up with both file:// and content:// is that I'm allowing the user to choose the program they wish to use to select a song file (ie music, astro, etc). Is there any way to convert one to the other or should I just test for each?

Comment: You can try poking through the `MediaStore` content provider stuff to see if you can come up with a way to get metadata given the file path, but I haven't tried that.

Comment: Cool. Thanks again for curing my blindness :]